# How to read and display images from a Drive directory using OpenCV and numpy?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to read an image from a directory on my drive, for this I use OpenCV, I convert the image to a numpy array of 32-bit floats and then display it, the problem I have is that the image is not displayed. The images correspond to chest X-rays and I'm working at Google Colab.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from skimage import transform
import numpy as np

img_r = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/images/T-NORMAL- (3).jpeg')

img1 = np.array(img_r).astype('float32')/255
img2 = transform.resize(img1, (150, 150, 3))

plt.imshow(img2)
```

[This is the result obtained from the first code. As seen, it is as if the image was not being well-read.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7wu2.png)

Thinking that I was not accessing the directory correctly, I used the os.listdir method, as shown in the following code, the images are not shown anyway.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage import transform


items = os.listdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/imagenes')
print (items)

for each_image in items:
  if each_image.endswith(".jpeg"):
   print (each_image)
   full_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/imagenes" + each_image
   print (full_path)
   image = cv2.imread(full_path)
   img1 = np.array(image).astype('float32')/255
   img2 = transform.resize(img1, (150, 150, 3))

plt.imshow(img2)
```

[This is what is displayed as a result of the second code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3G7V.png)

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this works

```
import cv2

img_r = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/images/T-NORMAL- (3).jpeg')

#to resize image
reimg_r = cv2.resize(img_r,(150,150))

cv2.imshow('xrays',reimg_r)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I tried your code, the cv2.imshow () method in Colab is replaced by cv2_inshow (), but the result is the same, there's no image displayed.                                                              `img_r = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/images/T-NORMAL- (3).jpeg')`

`img1 = np.array(img_r).astype('float32')/255`
`img2 = transform.resize(img1, (150, 150, 3))`

`from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow`
`cv2_imshow(img2)`
`cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: are you sure the image  you read is a valid jpg image ?  Can you view the image in another way , for example using Paint (on windows)  or  feh (on linux)  ?

Comment: Yes, the images are read correctly in other applications. I've even tried reading images other than X-rays and the same thing happens. I must be missing something that is not working.

Comment: May be the file is not a jpeg file  but a DICOM image format.  But if you can't read in opencv something seems wrong in your installation.   A look at DICOM images conversion: https://www.lifewire.com/dicom-file-2620657

Comment: For sure, the images have no DICOM format. I've trained my CNN with images of the same format, I have also tested the algorithm on another group of x-rays and now I want to predict specific images that are entered from a user, but in this case I cannot even read those images.

Comment: In the other cases, I didn't have the need to use openCV.

Comment: Try to reinstall  python opencv in accordance with your os system.

Comment: I reinstalled it using: `!apt-get -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python`, but there's no change

Comment: what distro os  are you using ?

Comment: I noticed that the image shows up when I only use `img = cv.imread ('T-NORMAL- (5) .png', 0)`, but when I access my drive directory, `img_r = cv2.imread ( '/ content / drive / MyDrive / images / T-NORMAL- (5) .png', 0) `, the image is no longer displayed and it is the same image. So the problem is with the addressing, any suggestions on that?

Comment: I realized that there must be no spaces to access the directories, with that consideration; the initial code works.

Comment: Nice , so every thing it's ok now.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Until the next question haha!